# Characterization of eventually periodic orbits

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto 2x^2-1$. We consider the sets

$A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,\mbox{the sequence of iterates $f^n(x)$ is eventually periodic}\},$

$B=\{\cos{(a\pi)}\,|\,a\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

We have the inclusion $B\subseteq A$, which follows from $f^n(\cos(a\pi))=\cos(2^na\pi)$ and the piegenhole principle, since for a fixed $a\in\mathbb Q$ the set $\{\cos(2^na\pi)\,|\,n\geq0\}$ is finite.

Is it true that $A=B$ ?